# Почему значение переменной прибавляет единицу, но не отнимает ее?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
btn = document.querySelector('button');
var msg = 0;
btn.onclick = function () {
  msg = msg + 1;
  function msgminus() {
    msg = msg - 1;
  }
  console.log(msg);
}
```

```css
button {
  height: 64px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: #5d81d2;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<button>Просто кнопка</button>
```

По идее в начале я создаю переменную, при вызове функции она добавляет единицу к своему значению, а в этой же самой функции создаю еще функцию, которая отнимает от той же переменной ту же самую единицу. В итоге должно всегда быть 0, но значение при каждом вызове функции увеличивается на единицу, в чем проблема?

Comment: Мб потому что вы объявляете функцию а не вызываете её

Answer (score 4):

"а в этой же самой функции создаю еще функцию, которая отнимает от той же переменной ту же самую единицу." - Вы просто объявили функцию, а не вызвали

```js
btn = document.querySelector('button');
var msg = 0;
btn.onclick = function () {
  msg = msg + 1;
  function msgminus() {
    msg = msg - 1;
  }
  msgminus();
  console.log(msg);
}
```

```css
button {
  height: 64px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: #5d81d2;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<button>Просто кнопка</button>
```

Comment: а можете подсказать, почему тут все время прибавляется? Ведь я вроде как вызываю функцию в setTimeout
http://prntscr.com/iqrjox

Comment: ну там вроде таймаут, отнимает через 3 секунды, а консоль лог сходу

Answer (score 1):

Как сказали ранее, у вас нету вызова функции, а конкретно строки `msgminus();`

```
    function msgminus() {
    msg = msg - 1;
    }   -это описание, что ваша функция делает.
```

`msgminus();`-это вызов функции

На мой взгляд, прописывать таким образом функцию в функции плохая практика.